# In Google Contacts, how to delete ALL "Other contacts" ALL AT ONCE?

Tags: google-contacts

***First***:
How to delete ALL "Other contacts" ALL AT ONCE ?
Not one at a time.
I want to delete ALL "Other contacts" in one motion.

**Second**:
How to prevent Google from collecting anymore "Other contacts" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Web based app, so it's off topic here.

Comment: Please read the tag(s) you included. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].